# Where can I find the source for libtracker-miner?

Tags: development, tracker, libraries

I've compiled Tracker from sources as described [here](https://live.gnome.org/Tracker/Documentation/Building). But when running 'tracker-control' it says something about not being able to load libtracker-miner-0.12.so.0 (see error message below). Where can I get this library? (I am not interested in using the pre-packaged .debs as I want to use it for development.)

```
tracker-control: error while loading shared libraries: libtracker-miner-0.12.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just a simple query I did to the apt-cache..

libtracker-miner-0.8-0 - tracker data miner library
libtracker-miner-0.8-dev - tracker data miner library - development files

have you installed those packages?

seems that the version of the library you need are old versions..you can even, install the new ones and do a link and see if the application runs, maybe there is some back compatibility
..anyway..if you compile it from sources...didn't it cry before?? it's strange, have you ran a ``configure'' script before compiling?

Comment: Thanks. I had to do a 'sudo ldconfig' before running program.